# Node js get/:parametro1&:parametro2 no funciona

Tags: javascript, nodejs

buenas gente estoy con node js queriendo llamar a dos valores pero no me esta andando no se en que me estoy confuiendo

```
app.get('/enso/:turno&:fecha', (req,res)=>{
   conexion.query('SELECT * FROM totalprod1 WHERE turno = ? AND fecha = ?', [req.params.turno],[req.params.fecha], (error, fila)=>{
       if(error){
           throw error
       }else{
           res.send(fila)
       }
   })
})
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 1):

Estas confundiendo la sintaxis de `parámetros de ruta` con la de `query strings parameters`.

Si quieres definir varios parámetros de ruta debes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
app.get('/enso/:turno/:fecha', (req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.params.turno);
  console.log(req.params.fecha);
})
```

Y para usar ese endpoint sería: `/enso/el-turno/la-fecha`, por lo tanto los parámetros serían:

- `req.params.turno -> "el-turno"`
- `req.params.fecha -> "la-fecha"`

---

Por otro lado, para obtener los query string parameters puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
app.get('/enso', (req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.query.turno);
  console.log(req.query.fecha);
})
```

Y para usarlos sería: `/enso?turno=turno&fecha=fecha`